# sass -v get Error phpstorm. Do not find SASS installation

Tags: ruby, terminal, console, sass, rvm

I' ve installed ruby with rubygems , version 1.9.2. I've made an update and also install version 2.1.0 (last stable). And now I'll get an error at my phpStorm console. Before everything worked great.

If I check my sass-Version, I always get these output in console (terminal)

```
    /Users/ssa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/scss --no-cache --update --watch --sourcemap --debug-info styles.scss:/Users/ssa/Sites/staging_shop/.../css/styles.css
/Users/ssa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'sass' (>= 0) among 41 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/ssa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/ssa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/ssa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/scss:22:in `<main>'
```

Work on a MAC OS x 1.6.8
What's my problem? I don't know. Meanwhile I think I installed to much .. and have no idea what I#m doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

first install `saas-rails` gem with command

```
gem install 'sass-rails'
```

and check sass version